# How can I put two navbar elements to the end in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am trying to put two navbar elements to the end of the navbar in Bootstrap 5 but it's not working

I've tried ms-auto with a div encapsulated around the log in and sign up elements but that didn't work. I've also tried float and text but that didn't work either.

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarPractice" aria-controls="navbarPractice" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarPractice">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Support</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Log In</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `w-100` or `flex-fill` class to stretch the navbar-nav element. Without that you have no space to implement `ms-auto`, which then works as expected. You'd use `ms-sm-auto` to only apply margin above the mobile breakpoint.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Navbar</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarPractice" aria-controls="navbarPractice" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarPractice">
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Support</a>
      <a class="nav-link ms-sm-auto" href="">Log In</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: use [bootstrap flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/) like @isherwood suggested.

Here is a bad practice option of setting the css yourself :

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #navbarPractice>div a.login {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarPractice" aria-controls="navbarPractice" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarPractice">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="">About</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Support</a>
      <a class="nav-link login" href="">Log In</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You rarely need custom CSS for things like this when using Bootstrap. Always make yourself familiar enough to avoid duplicating functionality this way.

Comment: whoops, sorry that was just the documentation that showed up first when I googled. sorry for the confusion. Yes, you're right, you should use what bootstrap offers and avoid customizing it yourself when possible.